# Xcode Duplicate Symbol Link Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, clang

I have files "A.c", "A.h", and "B.h","B.m".
I include "A.h" in both "A.c" and "B.h".

However, Xcode gives me a link error with numerous "duplicate symbols" found.

```
ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I compile my program?

**A.h**

```
#ifndef CPU_H_
#define CPU_H_
...
#endif
```

**A.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "A.h"
...
```

**B.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "A.h"
...
```

I'm getting duplicate symbols in A.c and B.m for the variables defined in A.h.

Comment: first of all you should be including the files on the .h files not on the .m...

Comment: @SpaceDog Updated that, sorry.

Comment: With Report navigator, you can find all 13 duplicate symbols. How they are declared in your `A.h`?

Comment: @OOPer all as unsigned char

Comment: "Xcode gives me a link error with numerous "duplicate symbols" found" Nearly always caused by importing a _.m_ file or a _.c_ file by mistake.

Comment: @matt I double checked, I'm only including .h files.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define global variables in header files. When you do, you get duplicate symbols.

#### A.h

```
#ifndef CPU_H_
#define CPU_H_
...
unsigned char GlobalVariable = 'a'; // ERROR: Causes duplicates symbols.
...
#endif
```

`GlobalVariable` is included (ie. directly copied into) A.c and B.m. This creates two copies of the same symbol. Therefore you get duplicate symbols.

---

To fix this problem, define your global variable in only 1 .c or .m file. Then you will safely only have 1 copy of that symbol. Now, how to you let B.h and B.m know about your global symbol? That's done by declaring (note: declare and define are different) `GlobalVariable` in A.h.

#### A.h

```
#ifndef CPU_H_
#define CPU_H_
...
extern unsigned char GlobalVariable; // Declare GlobalVariable
...
#endif
```

#### A.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "A.h"
...
unsigned char GlobalVariable = 'a'; // Define GlobalVariable
```